# asp.mvc view model not persisting newly assigned data when passed into view from httppost Controller

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, web

Whenever i run this code i have a problem passing the result from the controller to view from httppost method. The server side code is fine its just that when i assign a new result in the calculator.Result property i never see that newly assign value in the textbox in the view.The rest of the properties are populated with appropriate values.

Could anyone please help me how can i fix this? or what i am missing?

Thank you

Here is my code from .cshtml

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span2">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.FirstNumber)
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstNumber)
            </div>
            <div class="field-validation-error">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstNumber)
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span2">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SecondNumber)
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SecondNumber)
            </div>
            <div class="field-validation-error">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SecondNumber)
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span2">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SelectedFunction)
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedFunction, Model.Functions, "Please Make a Selection")
            </div>
            <div class="field-validation-error">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedFunction)
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span2">
                @Html.Label("Result: ")
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Result)
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <input type="submit" value="Load" />
        </div>

    }
```

Here is my code behind from the controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(CalculatorViewModels calculator)
    {
        //If the entries are valid
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            try
            {
                double firstNum = calculator.FirstNumber;
                double secondNum = calculator.SecondNumber;
                string selectedFunction = calculator.SelectedFunction;

                double result = -1;
                if (selectedFunction.Equals("1"))
                {
                    result = service.CombinedWith(firstNum, secondNum);
                }
                else if (selectedFunction.Equals("2"))
                {
                    result = service.Either(firstNum, secondNum);
                }

               calculator.Result = Convert.ToString(result);

                return View(calculator);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
               calculator.Result = "Error in calculating probability "+ex.Message;
                return View(calculator);
            }
        }

        //entries are not valid 
        else
        {
            return View(calculator);
        }

    }
```

here is my view model

public class CalculatorViewModels
    {

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Number between zero and one")]
    [Display(Name = "FirstNumber")]
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public double FirstNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Number between zero and one")]
    [Display(Name = "Second Number")]
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public double SecondNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select at least one function")]
    [Display(Name="Please Select a Function")]
    public string SelectedFunction { get; set; }

    //will be used to report exception as well if needed 
    public string Result { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Functions
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<SelectListItem>()
            {
                new SelectListItem{ Text="CombinedWith",Value="0"},
                new SelectListItem{Text="Either",Value="1"}
            };

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: for kicks and giggles, add in a "string testResult = calculator.Result;" after the "calculator.Result = Convert.ToString(result);" and add in a break point to make sure that value is actually being assigned to the model

Comment: @dave k i have already done that. A workaround would be use to view bag though

Comment: Are you sure you're not throwing an exception?  We can't tell what "service" is or what the methods do.  Try commenting out the try/catch block and see if any exceptions are raised.

Comment: Most likely this is a result of `ModelState` taking precedence over your model when using the HTML helpers. You'd need to clear `ModelState["Result"]` using `ModelState.Remove()`. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680982/changing-viewmodel-properties-in-post-action for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: Wow, 2 answers within an hour for a question that is a year old....

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your view, dump out the contents of your model just for a sanity check. Use HTML.Raw(..) or something and then view the page source to check the result is actually being set.

Something like

```
@{
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
}
```

Use JavaScript to write out the model to the console or something.

Let me know how you get on and if the result is getting set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach...

1) Update your view to add a click handler for the submit button and handle it in javascript

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span2">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.FirstNumber)
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstNumber)
            </div>
            <div class="field-validation-error">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstNumber)
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span2">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SecondNumber)
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SecondNumber)
            </div>
            <div class="field-validation-error">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SecondNumber)
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span2">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SelectedFunction)
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedFunction, Model.Functions, "Please Make a Selection")
            </div>
            <div class="field-validation-error">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedFunction)
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span2">
                @Html.Label("Result: ")
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Result)
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <input type="button" value="Load" id="btnSubmit" onclick="submitForm();"/>
        </div>

    }

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '@Url.Action("Index")';

    function submitForm() {
        var data = {};
        data.FirstNumber = $('#FirstNumber').val();
        data.SecondNumber = $('#SecondNumber').val();
        data.SelectedFunction = $('#SelectedFunction').val();
        $.post(url, data).done(function (result) {
            $('#Result').val(result);
        });
    }


</script>
```

Modify the controller to return Json data

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
..
..

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(CalculatorViewModels calculator)
        {
            //If the entries are valid
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                try
                {
                    double firstNum = calculator.FirstNumber;
                    double secondNum = calculator.SecondNumber;
                    string selectedFunction = calculator.SelectedFunction;

                    double result = -1;
                    if (selectedFunction.Equals("1"))
                    {
                        result = service.CombinedWith(firstNum, secondNum);
                    }
                    else if (selectedFunction.Equals("2"))
                    {
                        result = service.Either(firstNum, secondNum);
                    }

                    calculator.Result = Convert.ToString(result);

                    return Json(result);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    calculator.Result = "Error in calculating probability " + ex.Message;
                    return Json(0);
                }
            }

            //entries are not valid 
            else
            {
                return Json(0);
            }

        }
```

Do not forget to add jQuery library to scripts folder and add a reference to Newtonsoft.Json. Hope this helps.